# Why do I need Java 6 to run Pycharm?

Tags: java, pycharm

Every time I try to open Pycharm it says: You need Java 6.
What does Pycharm have to do with Java 6 and where can I download it?

Comment: No you don't.  It runs just *fine* on Java 7.

Comment: Because it is probably written in some JVM language :), download java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Maybe you could add some more details to this.  What system are you running on?  (What version of Java do you have installed locally, if any - is it Oracle of OpenJDK?)

Answer (score 3):

Pycharm is based on the same framework as IntellJ, which is written in Java.

Hence you need Java to run it.  For Windows it may be sufficient to install Java from http://java.com/en/download/ as directed to run Pycharm - if not, you need to install manually from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.

Note that the error message is slightly confusing.  A better wording would be "Requires Java 6 or newer to be available" - this is possible as new releases of Java traditionally has been very backwards compatible.

(I cannot unconditionally recommend OpenJDK except for advanced users, as I have seen unsatisfactory results on Ubuntu).

---

2020 edit:  OpenJDK is now fully recommendable (a lot has happened since 2015).  Some downloads include a runtime JVM so PyCharm works out of the box.

Comment: Yes, PyCharm is written in Java, but you don't require Java **6** to run it.

Comment: @Makoto The error message is apparently not precise enough for you.  Would "You need Java 6 *or newer* to run PyCharm" be good enough for you?

Comment: If it were the case that it could handle Java 6+ on that system, absolutely.  But, we don't know enough; it could  be that they're [impacted by this particular issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks) that JetBrains is aware of already with newer Mac OS X machines and their products.  But just saying that you need Java 6 to run it is still wrong.

Comment: @Makoto Also there is the case of the vendor actually having _TESTED_ the product on a given platform and Java version.  Java 7 and 8 broke some things which worked on Java 6.  Just ask anyone who wrote Java WebStart applications.

Comment: @Makoto "But just saying that you need Java 6 to run it is still wrong." - then try running it with Java 5...

Comment: I maintain, both from the standpoint of us not knowing their actual system and configuration, and that I use IntelliJ IDEA (and PyCharm, to an extent) on Java 7 on Linux:  there's no hard and fast rule that you need Java 6 to run PyCharm.  We need more information. Your answer is more a [mathematician's answer](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MathematiciansAnswer) than actually something that goes to solve the problem.

Comment: In my opinion you are focusing on the wrong thing due to a slightly unfortunate wording of a JetBrains programmer.  This particular error text is shown if Java is unavailable (which is perfectly possible when installing PyCharm on a box withouth Java) and not when the Java found is not version 6.

Comment: If that's the case, then we *still* need more information.  Do they even *have* Java installed?  What system are they running?  There are too many unknowns to just answer it like this.  It doesn't feel like anything's really being gained from this answer; it doesn't give insight into a similar problem that other people may be having.  We just need more information from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the IDE is written in Java (since [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) also makes intelliJ I suspect this is the case); as for Java 6 (specifically) you can get it from Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) or from openjdk [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/) but you can almost certainly run it with a more recent version like Java 7 or Java 8.